android studio build could not move temporary workspace
I'm trying to build my project in android studio, but it throws this error:

Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\hp.gradle\caches\8.9\transforms\7a91ea941edcd7bffa2a6a13dc6831b0-6ed273f2-022e-4192-8436-9855986a2387) to immutable location (C:\Users\hp.gradle\caches\8.9\transforms\7a91ea941edcd7bffa2a6a13dc6831b0)

Syncing an android studio project

I solved the issue by following these steps:
change name of folder from:
7a91ea941edcd7bffa2a6a13dc6831b0-6ed273f2-022e-4192-8436-9855986a2387

to:
7a91ea941edcd7bffa2a6a13dc6831b0

After trying this for about 5-6 different errors, the issue was resolved.
